# Exporting useState hook

Tags: react-native

How would I go about exporting the useState hook?
Exporting a variable is pretty straight forward, but I am not sure how to do it with useState.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Storage = () => {
    [data, setData] = useState("")
}
```

If I try to import Storage somewhere and run Storage.setData() I get a "setData is not a function error.

Comment: please try this
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Storage() {
    const [data, setData] = useState("")
}
export {Storage};

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to use Storage as a component, you may want to use useState in the parent and pass it down as props, then use const Storage = (props) => {} and access via props.attribute.

Comment: I get the same error. When I import it tries to find _Storage.Storage.setData()

Comment: @clash this is what I am doing now, but I have multiple function that use the useState setter and I'm sending it as a prop every time, so I just thought it was a lot of repeating code.

Comment: @fuzz I know what you mean. This is a a little bit of my problem as well. You can use useReducer if this would help: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html
But letting the parent access the stateSetter of a child is not very good practice I think.

Comment: @clash I am not sure how useReducer would help as it mostly deals with sub-values or when using more then one state. Right now I have three functions that gets called with the setter, loadData(setData, index), retrieveData(setData) and deleteData(setData, index). So it would be nice if Storage already had access to the setter, but maybe this is the way it is supposed to be done.

Comment: @clash Did you mean I should gather all functions that uses the setter under one reducer function and then just call it with the setter using different actions?

Comment: That would be my approach to your problem, yes. I had the problem of having multiple states in the parent and passing the state along with its setter eg. to a modal. The modal (wrapped in a child component) had 10+ props I had to set, which is ugly. Combining all states into a single useReducer managed state and only pass the dispatch to the child, which can now call the actions was a very clean way for me to handle it.

Comment: Btw. I don't know if this is what you want, but if you just want a storage functionality, maybe AsyncStorage would help? You could just write some native JS functions under one Storage namespace?

Comment: @clash Yeah I think a reducer will be the way to go =) Yes I am using ASyncStorage, then using a hook to know when to save, load and display new updates on the screen. I am not sure how namespaces work.

Comment: With namespace here I just meant a Storage object holding the functions, like a class. export const Storage = { func1: () => {}, func2 => {}}; Call Storage.func1(). If you use typescript, there is the namespace keyword, but you would need to google it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the component state elsewhere, so in order to do so you can make use of useContext in React and create a provider for which you can pass setData function as value and use it any where down the component tree

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const DataContext = createContext('');

export const DataProvider = ({children}) => {
const [data, setData] = useState("");
return (
<DataContext.Provider value={{ setData }}>
  {children}
</DataContext.Provider>
);
}
```

Now you can simply use setData down anywhere in the children components. I hope it solves the purpose.

In other file whereever you need to use it you can simply update the state value as

```
export const Component = () => {
const {setData} = useContext(DataContext);
useEffect(()=>{
setData('updated data');
},[])
}
return(<>children component updating the state</>);
}
```

Comment: the other file you mentioned should be a child component or any other component can use it from datacontext?